# Connect to an ADO.NET database using ODBC

Tags: ado.net, odbc

We have a bespoke column based database which we access progamatically using its ADO.NET driver which we wrote in-house.  However a colleague wants to use Excel etc to access this database using ODBC.

I expected to find some form of connector to provide an ODBC connection over an ADO.NET datasource (or some config in the ODBC) but I can't find anything.

I know this is using a new tech to connect to a much older one, but its what they want! So if anybody knows of a way to do this it would be much appreciated.

Cheers
John

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you've created a ADO.NET driver first, as opposed to an ODBC driver first. This sounds a little crazy as everyone knows you can access ODBC driver from ADO/NET but not the other way round.

ODBC is actually a much better interface and used by far more applications, is you question actually correct??

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: We required *programmatic* access to a variety of different database using a common coding API - ADO does this much more cleanly than ODBC - its what it was designed for - and is built into .NET. You can just swap from an OracleProvider to a SQLProvier to our own provider and everything continues to work.  With DAAB on top of this you don't even need to be aware of the database at all you just have a named connection and the physical db is completely abstracted.